# Error while running script in SQL

Tags: sql

This is my script to ask the user to input data values for each item, now my question is if the first values are

```
Criminal_ID Last First Street City   State Zip   Phone V_status P_status
1015       Fenter Jim       Chesapeake VA  23320           N      N
```

and there is no Street or phone listed how do I run this and not get an error. It also says No value needs
to be entered at the prompt if it should be set to the DEFAULT column value.

```
INSERT INTO Criminals 
    VALUES ('&Criminal_ID', '&Last', '&First', '&Street', '&City','&State','&Zip', '&Phone', '&v_status', '&p_status');
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the `INSERT` Syntax

```
    INSERT INTO Criminals (ColName1, ColName2, ColName3... etc)
    VALUES (Value1, Value2, Value3... etc)
```

Make sure that the number of columns equals the number of values separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer, use `DEFAULT` in values-list:

```
INSERT INTO Criminals VALUES (Value1, Value2, DEFAULT, Value4, DEFAULT, ...)
```